# Adding individual List Item to another List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to combine two lists I have so that there are no duplicates in the list.  First thing I do is grab all the users who can approve.

```
var allUsers = _dbContext.UserRoleClientEmployeeAssignments.Where(urcea => urcea.CompanyID == employee.CompanyID && urcea.ClientID == employee.ClientID && urcea.Users.Enabled).ToList();
var allApproveUsers = allUsers.Where(urcea => urcea.ApproveAllPTO).ToList();
```

Then I get all my department users who can approve

```
var deptSecurityUsers = _dbContext.UserDeptDivSecurities.Where(udds => udds.CompanyID == employee.CompanyID && udds.ClientID == employee.ClientID && udds.Department == dept && udds.ApprovePTO).ToList();
var deptApproveUsers = allUsers.Where(au => deptSecurityUsers.Any(ds => ds.UserID == au.UserID)).ToList();
```

After that I go through the list and if it doesn't exist in `allApproveUsers` I try to add it.

```
object concatUsers = null;
// check for existing user
foreach (var deptUser in deptApproveUsers)
{
     var exists = allApproveUsers.FirstOrDefault(e => e.UserID == deptUser.UserID);
      if (exists == null)
      {
          concatUsers = allApproveUsers.Concat(new[] {deptUser}).ToList();
      }
}

return (List<UserRoleClientEmployeeAssignment>) concatUsers;
```

I have 9 items in `allApproveUsers` and after I go through the 35 or so `deptApproveUsers` I only have 10 items in the list regardless of having 15 items that should be added.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You always add `allApprovedUsers` (which count is 9) to a single `deptUser` (that's why `concatUsers` always remains 10). You can try below:

```
allApprovedUsers = allApprovedUsers.Concat(new [] {deptUser}).ToList();
```

instead of

```
concatUsers = allApprovedUsers.Concat(new [] {deptUser}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to have some helpful extension functions for doing this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> rest, params T[] first) => first.Concat(rest);
public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> rest, params T[] last) => rest.Concat(last);
```

Also, there is an exists test in LINQ already:

```
 if (!allApproveUsers.Any(e => e.UserID == deptUser.UserID))
      allApproveUsers = allApproveUsers.Append(deptUser).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use LINQ to get rid of the duplicates?

```
allApproveUsers.AddRange(deptApproveUsers);
var uniqueUsers = GetUniqueValues(allApproveUsers).ToList();
```

Where:

```
private static IQueryable<T> GetUniqueValues(IQueryable<T> sequence)
{
    return from s in sequence 
           select s;
}
```